# OR condition in java substring method

Tags: java, string

While parsing the dynamic input string using the java substring method with start and end indexes, Can we use or condition in the end index of the substring method? Meaning end index could be either ')' or ',' for my use case.

Ex: my input string have below two formats

```
inputformat1 : Student(name: Joe, Batch ID: 23) is updated
inputformat2 : Student(name: John, ID:0, Batch ID: 2503, Result: pass) is updated
```

Now I am interested to get the "Batch ID" value every-time. I wanted to achieve this by substring method. Now I'm able to get the batch id value If I use any one of the indexes i.e, ')' or ','

```
String batchId= input.substring(input.indexOf("Batch ID: ")+9,input.indexOf(")"));
```

Can someone help me to the way to batch Id value basing on different end indexes?

Comment: Shortest solution would be to use `Math.min(tail_old.indexOf(")"), tail_old.indexOf(","))`, however this seems like an excellent use case for using regular expressions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex with `replaceFirst` to solve your problem for example ;

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Student(name: Joe, Batch ID: 23) is updated",
        "Student(name: John, ID:0, Batch ID: 2503, Result: pass) is updated"
);
for (String string : strings) {
    System.out.println(
            string.replaceFirst(".*Batch ID:\\s+(\\d+).*", "$1")
    );
}
```

Outputs

```
23
2503
```

---

If you want multiple groups you can also use Patterns like so :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("name:\\s+(.*?),.*?Batch ID:\\s+(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher;
for (String string : strings) {
    matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(
                String.format("name : %s, age : %s", matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2))
        );
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
name : Joe, age : 23
name : John, age : 2503
```

Comment: Can I use the same replaceFirst method to get name value as well? please update the regex for name as well

Comment: @JavaLearner how about you learn about [Java Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)?

Comment: @JavaLearner In this case its better to use Patterns to get  multiple cases check my edit!

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. will upvote the answer once I get sufficient reputations i.e.15

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Math.min():`

```
String batchId = input.substring(input.indexOf("Batch ID: ") + 9,
                     Math.min(tail_old.indexOf(")"), tail_old.indexOf(",")));
```